# Blank Page in Google Chrome

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Try to load my own created page with using Laravel + Blade, but then the browser only displays the output a sec then disappears. I have no idea what is going wrong, everything in my code doing fine and without errors... Any thoughts???

I'm running this page using **php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public**

This is web.php:

```
Route::get('/products/create', 'ProductsController@create');
```

This is ProductsController.php:

```
public function create(){
    return view('products.create');
}
```

This is create.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <h1>Add new product</h1>
    <form action="/products" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <div class="container">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="pName" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Product name</label>
                <input id="pName" 
                    name="pName"
                    type="text" 
                    class="form-control @error('pName') is-invalid @enderror" 
                    value="{{ old('pName') }}"  
                    autocomplete="pName" 
                    autofocus>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="pCat" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Category</label>
                <input id="pCat" 
                    name="pCat"
                    type="text" 
                    class="form-control @error('pCat') is-invalid @enderror" 
                    value="{{ old('pCat') }}"  
                    autocomplete="pCat" 
                    autofocus>
            </div>
        </div>
       <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
@endsection
```

Here's the webpack.mix.js:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .mixbrowserSync('localhost:8000');
```

It seems like the @extends('layouts.app') is not working, because when I removed it, the page could run tho. Any solution to solve it or did missing some dependencies to install??

Comment: did you check browser console ?

Comment: yea I did, but it didn't show up any error. Just seeing this "You are running Vue in development mode.
Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production."

Comment: You need to run through the steps to have your Javascript and CSS files [compiled](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix). Have you completed that successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Look in your Laravel log file normally located at `/storage/logs/laravel.log`

And you may want to serve it with artisan instead:

```
php artisan serve
```

> Local Development Server If you have PHP installed locally and you
>   would like to use PHP's built-in development server to serve your
>   application, you may use the serve Artisan command. This command will
>   start a development server at http://localhost:8000:

https://laravel.com/docs/master/logging

https://laravel.com/docs/master/installation

Comment: yea I did try php artisan serve, it responds to me http://127.0.0.1:8000 as Laravel development server started, and I add the path which what I had written in my web.php and route.js, well it just ends up keep loading that page...